# Docker container and Gcloud port forwarding

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose, gcloud, portforwarding

I have a Docker container running in my local machine and I should need to call a REST which is exposed on a private VPN in the Google Cloud Platform.

Let's say that this REST is exposed by the machine **external.service.com**.
In order to reach it from my local machine I have performed the following steps:

1. run the command on che Google Cloud SDK Shell: `gcloud compute ssh test-2 --ssh-flag="-L 2001:192.168.0.10:100"`. Where **192.168.0.10:100** is the IP corresponding to **external.service.com** inside the VPN. This permits me to reach that IP from **localhost:2001**
2. add the following line in my **host** file on Windows 10: `127.0.0.1 external.service.com`

Now on Postman i can reach the "private" REST service by the URL https://external.service.com:2001/api

For testing purposes I should reach the same REST service from a Docker container running on my local machine.
I know that for accessing host machine from within docker container I need to use the IP of my machine's active interface, since every Docker container will reference 127.0.0.1 to itself.

So i have added the following propertie in my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
   extra_hosts:
      - "external-service.com:192.168.xxx.x"
```

Where 192.168.xxx.x is my IP address.

Given this information, calling the REST service exposed by **external.service.com** inside my Docker container, I obtain the following error:

```
org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to external.service.com:2001 [external.service.com/192.168.137.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

In conclusion it can't say to Docker to convert **external.service.com** into **localhost:2001** or **(192.168.xxx.x:2001)** to reach the REST service reachable by the Google Cloud port forwarding.

Can you help me to see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You docker-compose snippet has `external-service.com` instead of `external.service.com`. Is it just a type in your post?

Comment: Also, the error has an IP in it which is a local one. So, maybe you have another DNS in your network resolving that IP?

Comment: @PramodhValavala `external-service.com` was just an example. For correctness i should have written `external.service.com`. Therefore, the IP in the error corresponds to my local machine IP, this is resulted by the property given in the `docker-compose.yml`